# Can not do Response.Redirect when I use WebClient with Silverlight 4.0 to call aspx page

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, webclient, response.redirect, server.transfer

I am working on a Silverlight Project. 
When i saved a jpg picture into a memorystream to save it
into the Context.InputStream, it is working fine.
I am calling an aspx page who thread the upload into the server.

But i can not do a "response.redirect" or "server.transfer" when the upload is done or failed .
Is it because I call  my aspx page from Silverlight using WebClient ?

Please find the code in Silverlight below :

```
 private void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream data){ 

 UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:52544/WebForm1.aspx");

//add a parameter filename  into the queryString

ub.Query = string.Format("filename={0}", fileName);

WebClient c = new WebClient();

c.OpenWriteCompleted += (sender, e) =>
   {

      PushData(data, e.Result);
      e.Result.Close();
      data.Close();
   };
c.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri);
}
```

On the aspx page, I have this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {             
                // get the filename

                string filename = Request.QueryString["filename"].ToString();

                // create a file on the server dir

                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Server.MapPath("~/AppData/" + filename)))
                {
                    SaveFile(Request.InputStream, fs);
                }

                    Response.Redirect("uploadOk.aspx", true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }


        }


        private bool SaveFile(Stream stream, FileStream fs)
        {
            bool isSaved = true;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            try
            {
                // copy the stream into the file

                while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                isSaved = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                isSaved = false;
            }
            return isSaved;
        }
    }
```

I have tried response.redirection("uploadOk.aspx",false) too and it is not working.
I got the following exception “[System.Threading.ThreadAbortException] = {Unable to evaluate 
expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}”

Do you have an idea how i can do a redirection using a WebClient ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that the upload fails but because it is on a different thread, SL does not show the correct error. Try adding code to log the error when it happens and see what the error is. You can do this on the server as well.

I suspect the problem is header is already written so it cannot redirect.

Try this since I think the problem is 100-continue:

```
 c.Headers.Add( HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive, "false");
 c.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Expect, "");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I dont have the method c.Headers.Add in Silverlight. I have only AllKeys,AsQueryable,Cast,... but not Add method.I think you are right the problem is because the headers is already written. Can you help me please to fix this ? Thx in advance.